# Скрыть/показать кнопку после срабатывания функции используя ng-show angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Есть кнопка лайки, так вот когда пользователь не залогинен, она должна быть скрыта, когда залогинен - показана. Как это сделать? 
Как я понимаю, когда срабатывает, функция логина должно вернуть переменной значения  `true`. Но я не знаю, как задать условия `if`, когда функция сработала. Или, возможно, есть более простое решение ...
Код кривой, но он работает, не судите строго...
Код контроллера:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state,$ionicHistory) {
        $scope.user = {};
        // Кнопка скрыта по молчинию 
        $scope.registered = false;
        $scope.login = function() {
        var str="http://www.manaspp.hol.es/user-details.php?e="+$scope.user.email+"&p="+$scope.user.password;
            $http.get(str)
            .success(function (response){
                $scope.user_details = response.records;

                sessionStorage.setItem('loggedin_name', $scope.user_details.u_name);
                sessionStorage.setItem('loggedin_id', $scope.user_details.u_id );
                sessionStorage.setItem('loggedin_phone', $scope.user_details.u_phone);
                sessionStorage.setItem('loggedin_address', $scope.user_details.u_address);
                sessionStorage.setItem('loggedin_pincode', $scope.user_details.u_pincode);

                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                    disableAnimate: true,
                    disableBack: true
                });
                lastView = $ionicHistory.backView();
                console.log(str);

                    $state.go('profile', {}, {location: "replace", reload: true});
            if ( //Что тут писать что бы вернуть true когда функция login сработала?  )){
                $scope.registered = true;
            }



            })
            .error(function() {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Login failed!',
                        template: 'Please check your credentials!'
                    });
            });
        };

            this.Likedd = function(){
        $scope.userid = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedin_id');
        $scope.id= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_id');
        var str="http://www.manaspp.hol.es/like.php?email="+$scope.userid+"&l="+$scope.id;
        $http.post(str);
    }
})
```

Код кнопки:

```
<div class="button-bar" ng-controller="loginCtrl as loginCtrl"> <button  ng-show= "registered" class="button button-assertive button-clear button-block  icon ion-android-favorite" ng-click="loginCtrl.Likedd()" ></button> </div>
```

Вопрос возможно и очень глупый, но я не могу разобраться ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<div class="button-bar" ng-controller="loginCtrl as loginCtrl"> <button  ng-
show= "loginCtrl.isLogin()" class="button button-assertive button-clear 
button-block  icon ion-android-favorite" ng-click="loginCtrl.Likedd()" >
</button> </div>
```

В коде функции напишите проверку авторизации:

```
function isLogin(){
    return angular.isDefined(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedin_id'));
}
```

Ну и в контроллере зарегистрируйте функцию:

```
this.isLogin = isLogin;
```

Comment: Не выходит, ну или возможно я не там прописываю код...function isLogin(){
    return angular.isDefined(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedin_id'));
}
 this.isLogin = isLogin; я прописываю внутри контролерра loginCtrl

Comment: Получается что эту кнопку не видно даже когда ты логинешся ..

Comment: Возможно вы имеете еще идеи?

Comment: А можно весь получившийся код посмотреть?